# Required @OA\Info() not found when run php artisan l5-swagger:generate

Tags: php, laravel, yaml, swagger

I'm new to developing with Laravel and I would like some help documenting an API using Swagger with the darkaonline/l5-swagger library.

I've been following the documentation, but I'm still having some trouble. I'm not sure how to configure the Swagger library or how to generate the documentation.

Would anyone be able to help me out?

I'm structuring the documentation like this:

```
app/Swagger/parameters/QueryParameters.yaml
app/Swagger/paths/products/get.yaml
app/Swagger/responses/SuccessResponse.yaml
app/Swagger/schemas/ProductSchema.yaml
app/Swagger/api-docs.yaml
```

In my api-docs.yaml file the api description looks like this:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Nome da Sua API
  version: 1.0.0
  description: Descrição da sua API
  contact:
    email: contato@example.com
  license:
    name: Licença
    url: http://www.exemplo.com/licenca
paths:
  /api/products:
    get:
      $ref: './paths/products/get.yaml'
      tags:
        - Products
```

Although the info is present, it does not identify.

I made these settings in hopes of identifying the file:

config/l5-swagger.php

```yaml
'paths' => [
    // ... other settings
    'schemas' => base_path('app/Swagger'),
],
```

.env

```
L5_FORMAT_TO_USE_FOR_DOCS=yaml
L5_SWAGGER_BASE_PATH=app\Swagger
```